# How to fit UITextView within a shape in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there a way to set a UITextView within a custom shape that isn't a square. Basically I want the text to fit within a circle.

I managed to make a circle border around the text.

But the text stays within a square and any text under the border gets cut off.

Answer (score 1):

UITextView has a property called exclusionPaths where you can set an array of UIBezierPath in order to avoid those areas with text. In case of a circle you will have to get the path with the form for the 4 corners of the UITextView.

You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23297518/1514727), that can help you achieve what you want.

As an alternative you could build the TextKit stack and create a custom container subclass to define the shape, but I think the exclusionPath is easier.